# [R]How Can I Merge two tables by conditions like " a. key >= b. key " and select the max(c) record?

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I want to do the following Job in R :

I got two Tables -- table.A and table.B like :

```
table.A <- data.table(DATE = c(20110104, 20110105, 20110106, 20110107))
table.B <- data.table(ANN_DT = c(20101231, 20110105, 20110106), 
                      RPT = c(20100630, 20091231, 20101231))
```

and now I want to merge `table.B` into `table.A` by the following Rules:

1. for each record DATE in A, find all records in B whose `ANN_DT <= A.DATE`
2. select the record with max(RPT) and Merge into table.A

so the result should be like this :

```
    DATE    B.ANN_DT      B.RPT
1   20110104    20101231  20100630
2   20110105    20101231  20100630
3   20110106    20110105  20101231
4   20110107    20110105  20101231
```

Can I do this job directly by `data.table` functions instead of loops or `apply` funcs ?

Thanks Very Much !
sorry for poor English because I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
B[order(ANN_DT), cmax_RPT := cummax(RPT)][]
B[, ANN_DT2 := B[B, ANN_DT, on=c(RPT= "cmax_RPT"), mult="first"]][]
ans = B[A, .(DATE, ANN_DT=ANN_DT2, RPT=cmax_RPT), roll=Inf, on=c(ANN_DT="DATE")]
ans
#       DATE   ANN_DT      RPT
#1: 20110104 20101231 20100630
#2: 20110105 20101231 20100630
#3: 20110106 20110106 20101231
#4: 20110107 20110106 20101231
```

The first line stores the cumulative maximm value of `RPT`. The second line extracts the `ANN_DATE` value corresponding to that `max` value.

These are the only two columns we need to then perform a rolling join, which identifies, for each `A$DATE`, the largest value in `B$ANN_DT` that is `<=` that `A$DATE`. Then we just extract the `max` and corresponding `ANN_DT` value.

Since this does not materialise all combinations, this should be quite memory efficient. And since this doesn't evaluate `<=` condition for each `A$DATE`, this should be plentiful fast.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've had another crack at my original thinking below - is it likely to be hugely slower?

Comment: I just noticed when I tried your code on a large set of data, that I got the "*Join results in more than 2^31 rows*" problem.

Comment: @daisong, have edited. Should be fast and memory efficient. Please let me know how it went...

Comment: @Arun, Thanks man, I wanna know will it work correctly if the value of RPT column is not unique ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way: subset table b, sort the subset by 'RPT' and return the last row

```
table.A[, {
  table.B[ANN_DT <= DATE,][order(-RPT)][.N]
}, by = DATE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

table.A %>%
  merge(table.B) %>%
  filter(ANN_DT <= DATE) %>%
  group_by(DATE) %>%
  slice(RPT %>% which.max)
```

Comment: Have you tested the code?  It gives error for me `Error in merge.data.table(., table.B) : 
  Can not match keys in x and y to automatically determine appropriate `by` parameter`

Comment: Oh I was doing it with dataframes, not datatables.

Comment: ah, I have tested the code and got the save error message. Maybe dplyr pack can be only used on data.frame objects ? whaterver，Thx a lot！

Comment: @daisong - the issue is the `merge` function/method you used, which will call `merge.data.table`, and will expect keys to be set for each of `table.A/B` - you can explicitly call `merge.data.frame` and your code should work, but ideally you would use one of `dplyr`'s merging functions instead.

Comment: @thelatemail, I tried this, but it returned error : Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.6 Gb . sigh...